# Why is "se" used with "secum" in this quote from Livy?

Tags: syntax, grammar-identification, translation-explanation, reflexive-pronoun

In this quote from Livy (6.8.6):

> "ita quocumque se intulisset victoriam secum haud dubiam trahebat."
>
> "thus, in whatever direction he went, he carried certain victory with him."

The reflexive pronoun, "se", is deployed with, "secum"; a bizarre translation: "he carried himself (accusative, "se") certain victory with him ("secum")"; or, "wherever he advanced himself ("se trahebat"), he carried...", is better but doesn't sound right: does a general advance himself or lead his army?

The use of "se" works if it means, "he". This happens in indirect speech (accusative-infinitive) when the subject of an indirect statement is the same as the subject of the main verb; then, a reflexive pronoun must be used, in the accusative:

> "rex dicebat se hostes superaturum esse."
>
> "The king said that he ("se"; the king) would overcome the enemy." (Oulton, Book III, p.41).

Livy did not use an accusative-infinitive construction and "he" is already included in the two third-person verbs: "intulisset" & "trahebat".

What is the role of "se", here; what if it was omitted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lewis and Short include this on *infero*:

> 5. *Se*, to betake one's self to, repair to, go into, enter, esp. with the accessory notion of haste and rapidity.

That is, *se inferre* means more or less "to move".
You might argue that it's literally "to carry oneself into something", but that's too literal a reading.
A good dictionary will indicate if there is something noteworthy about a reflexive use.

The verb *inferre* seems to typically want an explicit object, so you can't just drop the reflexive pronoun.
Maybe you could say *arma inferre* instead of *se inferre*, but the meaning changes slightly.
Check the dictionary entry for details.

Even though both languages have a similar looking reflexive construction, they aren't always used at the same time.
It is sometimes more a matter of idiom than of logic.

Comment: llmavirta: Thank you. In that section of L&S there is this ex., "(visa) sed vi quadam sua inferunt sese hominibus noscitanda," = "but through a certain power of their own they force their recognition upon men,". Is this a gerundive-of-obligation? The gerundive, "noscitanda", appears to agree with ablative, "sua". A gerundive, in an oblique case (ablative) can be translated as a gerund, giving: "but with a certain power of their own (seen), they force their recognising upon men,".

Comment: llmavirta: Tricky; those upon whom the obligation falls go into the dative; but, "upon/ on" require an ablative. Fortuitously, "hominibus", is the same for both cases. Do you have a thought on this confusion? (I know that you are not keen on translating literally; but, I don't think the gerundive should just be glossed-over.) (Gellius 19.1.15)

Comment: @tony noscitanda modifies vi. They impose themselves upon people by a certain force that must be recognized. The hyperbaton makes it more emphatic.